# How to prevent SQL injection for email validation in android

Tags: android, regex

I want to perform UI validation in android. while validating email address, I want to check it is valid email address or not. But, I want to validate top-level domain and also i want to prevent SQL Injection from it.

Here is a pattern I used as follows :

```
^[A-Z0-9+_.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+$
```

Please suggest some Idea

Comment: SQL injection is a technique used for automated attacks. The user has much better ways of accessing your database than typing in "little Bobby Tables" code into a field in your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, It might help you to solve your expectations

```
 ^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}$
```

It will prevent SQL Injection while entering email address and also it will validate top-level domain names such as com, us, nz, au, ch like that